# iOS Swift 2 Twitter Login integration

Tags: ios, twitter, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to integrate Twitter login in my project. I am using Xcode7 and following [Twitter login tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation#url-scheme). But I am getting the error in AppDelegate `value of type 'Twitter' has no member start`. I have installed pod `'TwitterKit'` and added `#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>` in `bridging header`. Below is the code in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"hTpkPVU4pThkM0", consumerSecret:"ovEqziMzLpUOF163Qg2mj")

return true
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems like you are using `Swift2` but you are using `Swift3` method for `Twitterkit`

Use this `Swift2` method and try again, It should work for you

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
```

Comment: Yeah, error eliminated. Where will I get the swift2 code for twitter login?

Comment: @IPL10 Their documentation is full of swift3 code, So i am not sure where you will get this. But yes you can follow the swift3 code and just the name of method is little bit different, So you can type and wait until your xcode suggests you. Hope it solves your problem. You can accept it as answer if it solves your problem or if you want to ask some another question i will be happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Use this For `Swift4.0`

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
```